# Installing IKEA Lillangen high cabinet (with feet)

Tags: electrical, drill, installation, cabinets

I need to install a Lillangen high cabinet that has feet on the floor but as it's tall it needs to be secured with four screws. There is a stud I can use but I am scared of not screwing right into the middle of the stud and hitting a wire although I can't find any wires with my voltage meter on that wall. Everything I read about drilling into walls and avoiding wiring seems fairly vague.

[image]    [image]

Can I attach it using one stud and drywall for the other side? And do I need to use a molly bolt? Or an anchor or other kind of attachment? Is 1 1/4" enough or too long for wires? I'm still not sure about wires in drywall if I drill well away from the stud.

Would this kind of cabinet be safe to attach to only drywall since it has feet? Thank you.

[image]

Edited to show metal brackets to connect to wall.

Comment: Are the walls 2x6  outside walls or 2x4 inside walls?

Comment: 2x6 wire should be in middle .  should be    2x4 the same  should be ok

Comment: I think 2x4 inside walls with duplex next door so firewall in between so sort of inside and sort of outside. I'm a bit worried about not locating the stud properly and drilling to one side of the stud. How far in is the wire usually? Thank you!

Comment: I have seen fire wall double 5/8 drywall. Look for a out let take plate cover off should be able to see

Comment: If you are putting screw up 4 feet doubt any wire there .If double drywall screw to short .

Comment: The anchor twist into dry wall then screw go in ?

Comment: @RobertMoody -- I'm in the trades, so I should understand telegraphic comments, but y'all just aren't very lucid here. Remember that people who are coming here with questions need clear directions, and "The anchor twist into dry wall then screw go in ?" is nearly meaningless.

Comment: You  do know whole story.at 3 am helping  someone,  So as lucid as i was i was tired .And willing to stay up and help.  See your answer and do not really agree .You even  have a better way than Ikea .

Comment: If you put an anchor (like a molly) into drywall I think you are not very likely to damage a wire, because in the middle of the space between studs the wire is free to move around. It is where the wire is "trapped" inside a stud or near a fastener like a staple that damage is most likely.

Comment: Same boat here! Thanks for asking this question. May I ask what did you do eventually?

Answer (score 1):

I'd never tell you to ignore Ikea's excellent instructions, but 4 screws through the middle of the cabinet back might not be as good as 2 good screws with L brackets on the very top of the cabinet. If the back of the cabinet is flimsy 1/4" stock, then the 4 screws are extra useless.

If you choose to use brackets on top because you just want to keep the cabinet from falling over (as opposed to completely holding it up), you have a high probability of having one stud to screw into. There is always the chance that you'll hit electrical wire, but it's not that common. (Be extra careful if there's an outlet behind the cabinet, as that increases the chance that there's wire running down the adjacent stud.) Try to figure out how thick your drywall is by looking at outlets on the same wall, and size your screw accordingly.

For the second non-stud bracket, a toggle bolt should be solid enough. It's very unlikely that you'd hit a wire in the space between studs.

If I was buying L brackets for just this job, I'd get ones in the 2-3" range, preferably with 2 holes for the cabinet top and 1 hole for the wall. Predrill for the short screws that go on the cabinet top.

Comment: Did you say "Ikea's excellent instructions" with a straight face ? Perhaps you meant Ikea's excellent stick figure drawings. ;)o

Comment: Thank you Aloysius. I added another picture from Ikea's instructions to show the metal brackets that are for attaching to the wall. Sorry, it wasn't clear before. 

There's no outlets on that wall.

Comment: While not directly familiar with the cabinet in question, many of IKEA's cabinets have a flimsy back wall, that's why the bracket that attaches to the more substantive side wall.   The purpose is tip-over issue.   While stud attachment would be preferable, any anchor should suffice.

Comment: Having recently installed 80" tall IKEA cabinets, I can tell you that the angle brackets _screw_ into the wooden side of the cabinet, then a screw is driven through the bracket into the wall. The are, actually, well designed to prevent tip over. I _think_ they came with plastic wall anchors suitable for drywall, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your walls are sheetrock, buy a cheap stud finder and find the studs.  If you have a stud behind where you want this cabinet, use a 1-1/4" screw with the L bracket into the stud.  One is enough. It's not holding the shelf up, just keeping it from tipping.     If the shelf is between studs use self drilling drywall anchors, buy them in a kit with matching screws and you can't go wrong.  Don't use molly bolts, that's overkill and they are a huge PIA to remove later if you need to.

If your walls are plaster just use plastic anchors and both brackets.  Don't use drywall anchors and don't waste time looking for studs.  They are hard to find and you don't need them.  Simple plastic anchor into the plaster, and if you hit lath or stud drill into it just enough for the anchor to go all the way in.  You can buy a kit with anchors, matching screws, and the matching drill bit.  From your question I'm guessing this is something that would help you.

Some people are talking about the weak rear panel on Ikea furniture, and it's easy to understand why from the picture but I don't think the picture shows attachment to the rear panel.  I believe there is a slot in the rear panel that those brackets go THROUGH and they then attach to the vertical shelf member.  You should do it the way they recommend.  The top of the cabinet may not be suitable for this if the instructions don't say so.

Regarding wires, don't drill or screw directly above or below a socket or switch for the entire height of the wall and you ought to be safe.    Going into a stud at that height you are less likely to encounter a horizontal wire run, and with a 1-1/4" screw even less so.